# Using .toSource with javascript arrays

Tags: javascript

Here is the JavaScript I have

```
var testArr = [];
testArr["foo"] = "bar";
console.log(testArr.toSource());
//console.log(testArr["foo"]); //logs "bar"
```

the output I get is `[]`, which is not what I was expecting. Can someone give an explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: You are mixing objects with arrays.

Comment: @JoãoSilva Can you explain what that means, it would seem to me that you can't have a thing that is both an object and an array.

Comment: You can attach properties to an array. The most common example is the `length` property.

Comment: Could you explain what you were expecting? Also, keep in mind that `toSource` is non-standard (I *think* it's Firefox-only).

Comment: @JoãoSilva ahhh that makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't know what I was expecting, maybe `testArr` would be converted to an object, `({"foo":"bar"})`, or something that showed the stored data.

Comment: @johnthexiii: For that to work, you'd have to use an object instead, that is, `testArr = {}`. Also, use `JSON.stringify` instead of `toSource`.

Comment: @JoãoSilva you more or less answered my question by explaining that arrays can have properties attached to them. I didn't know that.

Comment: Some MDN links for reference: [`Object.toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource), [`Array.toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSource).

Comment: @JoãoSilva -- In Javascript, all native objects inherit from `Object`, thus you can attach properties to almost **anything**, not just objects.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher almost anything... what are the exceptions?

Comment: @johnthexiii -- Let me clarify that last comment:  "You can attach properties to **any** object, not just the base `Object` type."  I'm getting weird results when trying to attach properties to primitive values.  Under the Chrome console `var l = false; l.foo = 2; alert(l.foo);` yields `undefined`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I get the same thing in my spider-monkey console.

Answer (score 0):

Well. w3schools says it doesn't work on IE.

Also I've executed it in Chrome and a tipical console `> testArr` also printed `[]` even if `> testArr["foo"]` printed `bar`. So I think that asociative arrays are not iterated when outputing source.

Try changing the first line to:

```
var testArr = {};
```

That way it will be a common object.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This declares an array
var testArr = [];

// THis assign an object property.  Because it isn't a numeric array index,
// it doesn't show up as part of the array.
testArr["foo"] = "bar";

// .toSource() is not cross platform. 
// JSON.stringify(testArr, undefined, 2) is better
console.log(testArr.toSource());

// Yes, because that property exists.
//console.log(testArr["foo"]); //logs "bar"

It sounds like what you really want is this:

// Make an object that can take string properties and not just integer indexes.
var testObject = {};
```